# $mysqli->insert_id not working with PHP on openSUSE

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, mysqli

I'm in the process of moving a `PHP` application from an `Ubuntu` server to an `AWS openSUSE` instance.

The application does not work on the openSUSE box. The `API` fails for any call that has `$mysqli->insert_id`. Calls using `$mysqli` do work.

From reading around I have noted that this usually fails because of `auto_increment` not being implemented on the Database column. I migrated the `MySQL` database across from the `Ubuntu` hosted app. The table schema seems to be the same.

I have also looked at the server configuration files `php.ini` etc. and the `MYSQLi` extensions seem to be configured correctly.

It is for this reason I think it is a PHP related problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : To provide more information as requested.

The general structure of each API call that fails is.

1. The iOS sends a POST to the API
2. The API (built in PHP) inserts the information into a Table which has a Primary Key that auto-increments.
3. The API then uses $case_id = $mysqli->insert_id;, obtain the value of this primary key.
4. This value is returned to the iOS app.

Important - $case_id is being returned as 0.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  What's your query, what's the table schema for the query you're running.  What's the code that runs the query, what's the immediately executed code after the query is run?  I've never ever heard of `MySQLi::$insert_id` being a problem, ever, in php.  So, until further information - my answer is PEBKAC.

Comment: can you change the database access code? if yes! then port to `PDO`. see `http://in1.php.net/pdo`. other APIs are going to be obsolete soon!

Comment: Just to rule out that it's not a MySQL problem and it's a PHP problem can you provide more detail in how you migrated the database from Ubuntu? Are you sure that the auto_increment setting is properly migrated?

Comment: @pjp: No, `ext/mysqli` is not likely to be deprecated any time soon (unlike `ext/mysql` which is now deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0).

Comment: Hi guys, more information added in the EDIT. Thanks

Comment: i know..mysqli will not be deprecated just yet! but PDO is going to be a standard or probably is..thats why if its ported..then make it PDO based. it is also far more secured

Comment: @apokryfos, I can not confirm that it is properly migrated. I logged into check the schema on the table in question and it matched up. However, phpmyadmin was being used to create some tables on the Ubuntu app. And it is not being used anymore with the openSUSE one. Is there something I should be looking out for. Thanks

Comment: Is any data being added to the MySQL table? It almost sounds like the PHP code is returning 0 because it was unable to add data to the table. Perhaps MySQL database users weren't ported?

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading. . . https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54190 seems that "insert_id 'Works with libmysql, fails with mysqlnd.' ". Turns out that the openSUSE box has mysqlnd, the ubuntu box has libmysql. So I'm working on that now. Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: The link posted mentions: mysqli->insert_id will return zero after mysqli->get_warnings(). If you are doing mysqli->get_warnings() before the insert_id then you should use: ->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS `id`")->fetch_object()->id instead of the native call. Might be a workaround of that bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot an issue like this I would start by isolating where the problem is occurring.  Is the schema wrong?  If you log into the MySQL server using the MySQL shell and you attempt to manually insert a record, with a NULL for the auto-incremented (primary key?) column does the new record appear properly?  If you query using the same underlying SQL statement that's being generated and passed to the server from your PHP/mysqli component does it return the proper row(s)?

If it works using the MySQL shell on the DB server then what if you try the same from the API server?  Is it a permissions/ACL or networking issue?  If the it works from the MySQL shell on both the DB server and the API (web?) server then does it work from your PHP code?  Perhaps you can refactor your PHP to allow you to run tests/diagnostics from the command line (rather than attempting to initiate a transaction through the additional web/UI layers).  (This is generally a good idea when writing your web applications anyway).  Perhaps you can separate the web/form/ReST handling (view) from the code which passes data back into the DB (the model).  Thus you isolate the controller code from the rest and can re-use it for diagnostics and for monitoring.

If you can't get it working even from the DB server's only MySQL shell prompt then you probably have a problem in the schema.  Go back to the working DB server and perform a schema dump as described here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,128003,128105

Then restore that.  It should then be a completely empty database with your working schema intact.  If that doesn't work then it suggests you have some issues even lower (MySQL version and modules perhaps, missing some storage backends?)